# Actionscript 3 Facebook integration

Tags: facebook, sdk, actionscript, integration

I am developing a flash game and I want to integrate it with Facebook. It should be very simple integration. My app only need username and e-mail address. I searched the web not I still don't know how to do it. It seems to me very complicated. 
All I want is to connect my app to Facebook through Actionscript SDK, with few simple functions.
Can someone help me with a code to do that...I'll be very thankful guys :-)

Comment: your question is very broad, i think you should look at FaceBooks API, proberly use php to pass info back and forth between flash and facebook. also post some code of what attmepted you have made so some one can help you in the right direction.If you havent come up with anything i suggest you look at loading and passing variables from flash to php to get you started comunicating, plenty of tutorials with sourcecodes available.

Comment: Thanks :-) I thought I should look at PHP/ActionScript communication, but I was hoping to communicate with Facebook directly through ActionScript Flash with the ActionScript 3 SDK for Facebook.

Comment: iv looked at the SDK it is possible to comunicate straight with flash, im thinking its easier to use php java , as they seems to more documents on these languages, iv neverd used facebook so im only assuming and are more familiar with other languages thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a general question, but here are a few links that might help steer you in the right direction.  The first link has the SWC library and some examples:

Facebook ActionScript API resources:

- [libraries and examples](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=facebook%20actionscript%20api&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/&ei=Nzd7T5j8Ioe6iwKorvx0&usg=AFQjCNE9E354YpEzvOFDdkHTK4gMqGQXbw&sig2=cgB-AKziEBYZVkTrSUwV8g)
- [API documentation](http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html) (though fairly sparse)
- [Adobe page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html)

On their page, Adobe links to a [tutorial / walkthrough](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/10/create-a-mobile-facebook-flex-application-in-flash-builder-4-5-part-1.html) for building a mobile Facebook app that's pretty helpful, though it expands on a [desktop-based article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt1.edu.html) and references it regularly, so that can be a bit confusing, but it does get the job done.

Then you need to understand the Facebook Graph API - basically Facebook passes around objects that contain data pertaining to the user, their friends, etc (and of course, passing around this data is subject to the permissions your app has setup).  Facebook provides an online tool ([Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)) that let's you explore these objects for your own account.

Pouring over this information, I got my first flash-based mobile app talking to Facebook in a few hours.  There you go, ask a generic question, get a big swath of links to read that are only semi-related to your question.  =D

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I am currently working on integration via PHP :-)